# SQL - Limit the amount of results to group by

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to run this query;

```
SELECT artist, song, track, album, album_id, art, COUNT(artist) AS artistCount FROM listening_artist GROUP BY artist ORDER BY COUNT(artist) DESC
```

Which works fine, but I'd like it to work from only 30 results from the database, instead of the full database.

**I've tried this**

```
SELECT artist, song, track, album, album_id, art, COUNT(artist) AS artistCount FROM listening_artist LIMIT 30 GROUP BY artist ORDER BY COUNT(artist) DESC
```

Which returns nothing.

**I'm not after this**

```
SELECT artist, song, track, album, album_id, art, COUNT(artist) AS artistCount FROM listening_artist GROUP BY artist LIMIT 30 ORDER BY COUNT(artist) DESC
```

As it would be too late for the limit.

**What it's for**

It's to select the user's most listened to artist from within their last 30 played songs.

**My database**

```
+------------+----------+---------+---------+------------+-------+
|   artist   |   song   |  track  |  album  |  album_id  |  art  |
+------------+----------+---------+---------+------------+-------+
| T-Swift    |  22      | *NULL*  |   Red   |  9282781   | URL   |
|            |          |         |         |            |       |
+------------+----------+---------+---------+------------+-------+
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: your "returns nothing" one is a flat-out syntax error, which would suggest you have no error handling in your code to detect when the query blows up. Read the syntax: [select](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

Comment: Apply the limit within a Derived Table (Subselect) and learn how to format a Select-statement.

Comment: Why do You need the `GROUP BY`. It looks like an error or an undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, your second query returns no results because the syntax is invalid.

Instead use a sub select to limit the results:

```
SELECT artist, song, track, album, album_id, art, COUNT(artist) AS artistCount
FROM (
       SELECT *
       FROM listening_artist
       LIMIT 30
     ) AS recent_listening_artist
GROUP BY artist
ORDER BY COUNT(artist) DESC
```

Inside the sub select you can add additional ordering e.g. by the timestamp a song was played.

You did not specify your actual DBMS, so you might need to slightly adjust the syntax (this is MySQL), but it should at least give you a hint in the right direction.

Note that this will only give you one row per artist, which makes including tracks or albums in the output a bit pointless. See also [this MySQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7fa27a/4) for a small demo.

Comment: Thank you! It worked brilliantly! I had made a workaround, but I use this now.